# FastCGI sent in stderr primary script unknown while reading response header from upstream

Tags: php, nginx, centos, runtime-error

I have in `nginx.conf`

```
upstream php-fpm7.0
{
    server unix:/run/php-fpm/php7.sock;
}
```

I have in `conf.d/default.conf`

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    include php-fpm;
}
```

I have in `php-fpm`

```
fastcgi_pass    php-fpm7.0;
include fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME         $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
set             $path_info              $fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO               $path_info;
# Additional variables
fastcgi_index   index.php;
```

But i get error 404.
When i comment

```
#location ~ \.php$ {
#    include php-fpm;
#}
```

files are available

Error even if

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/php7.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

> FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading
>   response header from upstream

The same error if not using socket:

```
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
```

Centos 7

Update 1.

After i used:

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param FOLDER $document_root;
fastcgi_param FOLDER_SCRIPT $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

I got `$_SERVER['SCRIPT']` `/index.php` 
and `$_SERVER['FOLDER']` `/home/www/m-a-x/www`
and `$_SERVER['FOLDER_SCRIPT']` `/home/www/m-a-x/www/index.php`

When i back

```
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

all works.
Mystery.

Comment: Have you set a `root` directive within the `server` block?

Comment: yes, also i added it in `location ~ \.php$`

Comment: So `nginx` can see the file but `php_fpm` cannot. Are both services running under the same user?

Comment: Main processes running under root, child processes - under www. And file rights are 777.

Comment: Could it be related to SELinux policy? I am not an expert, but it may be something you need to check.

Answer (score 2):

You can always check nginx variables by adding them to return statement, for example:

```
location / {
    return 200 $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

1. Open the URL, a file will be downloaded, file will contain variables
   returned by nginx. For example /srv/www/index.php
2. Check that nginx/php-fpm user group has access to the file:

   sudo -u www stat /srv/www/index.php
3. Set permissions to read and execute the files for the www user group all along the path.

   chmod g+x /srv

   chmod g+x /srv/www

   chmod g+x /srv/www/index.php

Comment: Also you can add www user to your user group:
gpasswd -a www m-a-x